# Access Denied error when uploading multiple files in sequence using aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

As the final step of a CI Build process, I am using the following shell script to upload a single file at a time to an S3 Bucket:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Uploading the file: "$1
aws s3 cp "$1" "s3://BUCKET_NAME/$2$1" --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
exit;
```

When I call this script with a single file (using the command `sh upload.sh 'filename' 'path'`) it works okay, but when I call it in twice in quick succession the second shell script and other calls to the `aws` command line tool fail with the error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied

Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter UploadId, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

Individually the requests work, but when run together the later ones all fail with the same 'Access Denied' error message.  I assume this is a race-condition kind of error, but how should/could I avoid this problem?

Comment: I have added the `--debug` flag to my script, and that seems to make the uploads work more reliably.  Any reason why that would make a difference?

Comment: Did you notice any other information that might be relevant to the problem when debug was enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be resolved - the machine running the scripts (the Build Agent) was using two different connections when making the requests, and those connections each had their own external IP addresses (WiFi and Wired connections.) Only one of those IPs was allowed by the AWS Access Policy, causing the randomness and unpredictability of the uploading.